# Template no deduce el argumento

Tags: c++, function, template

Tengo un problema con este código y es que no consigue compilar al llamar a una función con templates desde el interior de otra (también con templates).
No puedo llamar a funciones desde otras.

```
template<typename T>
void reflexion(bintree<T> &arb);

template <typename T>
void wrap_reflexion(typename bintree<T>::node node);

template <typename T>
void reflexion(bintree<T> &arb){
  wrap_reflexion(arb.root());
}

template <typename T>
void wrap_reflexion(typename bintree<T>::node node){
  if (node.null())  
          return;  
      else
      { 
          typename bintree<T>::node temp; 
            
          /* recorro los subarboles */
          reflexion(node.left()); 
          reflexion(node.right()); 
        
          /* cambiar los punteros a nodo */
          temp     = node.left(); 
          node.left() = node.right(); 
          node.right() = temp; 
      }
}




int main(){

  // Crear un arbol y rellenarlo:
    bintree<int> Arb(7);

    Arb.insert_left(Arb.root(), 1);
    Arb.insert_right(Arb.root(), 9);
    Arb.insert_left(Arb.root().left(), 6);
    Arb.insert_right(Arb.root().left(), 8);
    Arb.insert_right(Arb.root().left().right(), 4);
    Arb.insert_left(Arb.root().right(), 5);

    reflexion(Arb);

  return 0;
}
```

El error del compilador:

```
ejercicio04.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void reflexion(bintree<T>&) [with T = int]’:
ejercicio04.cpp:31:18:   required from here
ejercicio04.cpp:38:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘wrap_reflexion(bintree<int>::node)’
   38 |   wrap_reflexion(arb.root());
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
ejercicio04.cpp:42:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> void wrap_reflexion(typename bintree<T>::node)’
   42 | void wrap_reflexion(typename bintree<T>::node node){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ejercicio04.cpp:42:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ejercicio04.cpp:38:17: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’
   38 |   wrap_reflexion(arb.root());
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Como se puede comprobar, no puedo llamar a reflexion() desde el main ya que esta llama a wrap_reflexion() y devuelve este error.

Comment: Qué compilador y qué versión de C++ estás usando?

Comment: Hola, estoy usando c++11 con g++.

Uso esta orden para compilar:

g++ -std=c++11 mirror.cpp bintree.h -o mirror

Me ha pasado infinidad de veces en otros códigos, así que tiene que ser algo generalizado

Comment: Te lo pregunto porque la respuesta puede variar en función del estándar que estés usando

Comment: ¿Podrías poner, por favor, la interfaz de `bintree` y de `node`?

Comment: Aquí dejo la carpeta de Drive con los documentos en cuestión, gracias:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X1MDfVscRuPZBjwH3mLlMIFIYI5s2tIV?usp=sharing

Comment: No, enlaces a drive no, primero por seguridad y segundo porque la pregunta no solo puede ayudarte a ti. Nadie va a mirar nada que no esté en la pregunta

Comment: Son varios ficheros muy extensos. No se como voy a especificarlo en la pregunta ya que no me va a dejar editarlo de esta forma

Comment: Por favor, consulta lo que es un [mcve]. El código que has puesto como ejemplo, ni es verificable ni es mínimo: es fácil condensarlo en poco mas de 20 líneas. ¿ Te has pasado ya por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: No te pido la implementación completa sino la interfaz. Tienes que aportar cierta información para que podamos responder a la pregunta.

Comment: Ese contexto no es deducible.

Answer (score 3):

El error que encuentras es reproducible con este código más corto:

```
template <typename T>
struct Estructura
{
    struct Interna {};
    Interna funcion() { return {}; }
};

template <typename T>
void f(typename Estructura<T>::Interna)
{
}

int main()
{
    Estructura<int> e;
    f(e.funcion()); // candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
    return 0;
}
```

Ese contexto no es deducible, ya que no estás deduciendo un parámetro plantilla si no una plantilla con parámetro, puedes solucionar el problema explicitando el parámetro plantilla:

```
int main()
{
    Estructura<int> e;
    f<int>(e.funcion()); // ¡Sin problemas!
    return 0;
}
```

O si eso no es aceptable, separa el problema en partes:

1. Deducir el parámetro plantilla del objeto.
2. Llamar a la función con el parámetro deducido.

```
template <typename T>
void f(typename Estructura<T>::Interna)
{
}

template <typename T>
void g(Estructura<T> &e)
{ //              ^ <--- Extraemos el parámetro...
    f<T>(e.funcion());
//    ^ <--- ... usamos el parámetro extraído.
}

int main()
{
    Estructura<int> e;
    g(e); // Llama a f<int>
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU/LCsIwEDwnX7EnSQ5az23pzYPgsT8Q4rYEmjTUVJDSb48brVVBPO1jdmZ2tPdb3SnXxhjQ@k4FhDLcPDplEeqKX8Iw6gCHZx0HxSfOluXRBRycgmkuOHsNzei06Z2QMMGAxHAJh5nTEf/tce3NGRqxrt5mZV3l@aIsyXn@K9GKLyZsMHFYQ73A3fqYLJKOcQGsMjSnmw8iARUgJWoFygKyDE6dsgoo2gPjbIm1J50Y7w)</kbd>. En el caso de tu código, bastaría con cambiar la función `reflexion`:

```
template <typename T>
void reflexion(bintree<T> &arb){
//                     ^ <--- Extraemos el parámetro...
  wrap_reflexion<T>(arb.root());
//               ^ <--- ... usamos el parámetro extraído.
}
```